# MYSQL dynamic code or concatenation operator to build

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write code to join column name with string, in mssql we use + symbol.

I have tried the following it is working but having some extra space ex:'tbl1   ' and from tbl_1. Hope there is better way to do this.

CONCAT Statement:

```
select CONCAT('insert into tbl_count_of_rows_after_migration select count (*) as row_counts, ''', table_name )    as Column1, 
 CONCAT(''' as ',table_name )    as Column2, 
 CONCAT (' from ',table_name)    as Column3, 
 CONCAT (';','')                 as column4 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'dbname';
```

Here is the result:

```
insert into tbl_count_of_rows_after_migration select count (*) as row_counts, 'tbl1 ' as tbl_1   from tbl_1 ;
```